# Undefined local variable or method 'session' in model test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application, and am trying to run a test involving my User model to see if the "Remember me" feature works. I'm using Rails' inbuilt `cookies` hash to store the cookies, and the `session` hash to store the current session. I've run various tests (integration, model, and controller) where I use the `session` variable, but for some reason in this particular case it isn't being recognized.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for #<UserTest:0x0000000658b5c8>
```

The error happens in the `else` block in the `log_in_as` method below:

`test_helper.rb`

```
...

def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  password = options[:password] || 'password'
  remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'

  if integration_test?
    post login_path, session: { email: user.email, password: password, remember_me: remember_me }
  else
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

I call `log_in_as` in my User test; both of these tests fail.

`user_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'
...
test "login with remembering" do
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
  assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
end

test "login without remembering" do
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
  assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
end
...
```

And when I remove that line of code from the helper, an error is thrown saying that `cookies` isn't recognized. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `session` hash [isn't available in models, only in controllers and views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) and controller and view tests.

Comment: Ah, I see, but this code is in the test suite... Does that still apply? Also, I have calls on the session hash within the `test_helper.rb` file. (refer to my response comment on the main question)

Comment: Yes. Available **only** in controllers and views and controller and view tests.